# How to remove reference of a class object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  document.querySelector('start'),addEventListener('click', () =>{
    var car = new Car('Audi');
    document.addEventListener('keyup', e=>{
      car.printName();
    })
  })
})

class Car{
  constructor(name){
    this.name = name
  }

  printName(){
    console.log(this.name)
  }
}
```

I am trying to create a simple game using JavaScript OOP. After the DOM loads and the player hits the 'start' button, a new Car object is created by passing the object's name property. For simplicity, the only method in the class for now is 'printName' which prints.

The problem is the previous object remains in the memory even though the game should reset whenever the player hits start button, since I have created a brand new object.

Notice, in the above code, whenever a player hits 'start' button two times and presses any key, the 'printName' method gets invoked for both new and old object. How can I tackle this problem?

Comment: Making you class Car a singleton would be a great choice. Or the other way (not recommended) would be to maintain a global reference to car instance and assign a new object when you start.

Comment: One issue is every time you click _start_ you're adding another event listener to the stack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix this issue by adding the `keyup` event outside the `click` event, so that the `click` event stops adding multiple `keyup` event listener to the stack like:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  var car;
  document.querySelector('start'), addEventListener('click', () => {
    car = new Car('Audi');
  })

  var handleKeyup = () => car && car.printName();
  document.addEventListener('keyup', handleKeyup, false)
})

class Car {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name
  }
  printName() {
    console.log(this.name)
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="start">Start</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that on every click of the start button you are creating a new keyup event listener because you are passing an anonymous (new) function.

To solve the issue, instead of an anonymous function you can pass a regular function into the `keyup listener` and add the `var car` declaration outside of the `start click listener` so that `car` becomes a global variable. Because the regular function (doSomething() below) always has the same address a new event listener won't be assigned on every click of the start button.

Another solution would be to move the onkeyup event listener declaration outside of the start click listener, but then it would not be tied to pressing the start button.

**Check below:**

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  var car;
  document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('click', () =>{
    car = new Car('Audi');
    document.addEventListener('keyup', doSomething);  // gets assigned only once
    document.addEventListener('keyup', () => {        // gets assigned every time
        console.log("BMW");
    });
  });

  // gets assigned once, after DOM loads, but is not tied to the start button
  document.addEventListener('keyup', () => {   
    console.log("PORSCHE");
  });
  
  function doSomething() {
    car.printName();
  }
});


class Car{

  constructor(name){
    this.name = name
  }

  printName(){
    console.log(this.name)
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="start" value="Start"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But i am still confused on how creating a regular function avoids the creation of multiple keyup event listener in the stack. I will do some research on my own. But if you can please explain or point me to some resources i can use to learn this.

Comment: @sammanadhikari I edited my answer to demonstrate all 3 different scenarios and to prove what I said above. You will see that the accepted answer above triggers the keyup event listener even when the start button has not even been clicked yet.

Comment: @sammanadhikari Hi, just wondering if you ran and tested the above example I made to see what I was saying.

Comment: Hi @Ivan86 . Thanks a lot for the help. Yes i tested the above code and it ran just fine. The results were as expected. Again thanks a lot for your time and sorry for the late reply.

Comment: @sammanadhikari Ok, thanks for letting me know. Just wanted to be sure you are aware of the differences in where to put the listener.